# NGINX we server is running, but requires more configurations. what can i do?

Tags: html, docker, nginx, yaml, localhost

I am just playing around with docker, & trying to launch a basic html file locally using docker.  the server is up and running but its not displaying the html text on the website. what configurations do I need to show the html text?

The error I'm getting:

"If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required."

**here's my code:**

**index.html:**

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<p1>docker</p1>
```

**dockerfile:**

```
FROM nginx
COPY C:\Users\X12X\Desktop\docker test
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'
services:
    app:
        shm_size: 128m
        build: .
        image: nginx
        volumes:
            - C:\Users\X12X\Desktop\docker test
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
```

I am totally new to docker, & im not sure what kind of configurations i need to do in order to show the HTML text on the localhost/8080 webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    app:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
```

The build context is very important here. In COPY command of your dockerfile, source path must be inside your build context.

This is the content of build context directory:

[image: tree -ah]

Also remember to run docker-compose in a detached mode (docker-compose up -d).

Answer (score 0):

You need either a [*server block*](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/#) to point your NGINX to the */test* folder, or to mount your *index.html* file at the default location: */usr/share/nginx/html*

1. Using the default NGINX location */usr/share/nginx/html*, you just need this *docker_compose.yml* (you don't need a Dockerfile):

   ```yaml
   version: '2'
   services:
     app:
       image: nginx
       volumes:
         - C:\Users\X12X\Desktop\docker:/usr/share/nginx/html
       ports:
         - "8080:80"
   ```
2. Adding a server block:

   1. You need to override the default a server block configuration file, in */etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf*:

      ```
      server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        index index.html;

        server_name_in_redirect off;

        root  /test;
      }
      ```
   2. You need to mount this configuration file in the configuration folder */etc/nginx/conf.d/* as well as the *index.html*

      ```yaml
      version: '2'
      services:
        app:
          image: nginx
          volumes:
            - C:\Users\X12X\Desktop\docker:test
            - C:\Users\X12X\Desktop\docker\default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 
          ports:
            - "8080:80"
      ```

Comment: After using that code above. it take me to a webpage which displays "402 FORBIDDEN" with "nginx/1.19.0" under it.

Comment: With which one, the solution 1 on the 2? (I just updated the second after a retesting of the correct file to use)